# How to work with specific parameter of a Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Treat an offer as a category in controller.

### The problem

I have a controller whose name is `ProductsController`. Inside it, I have an action called `Category`. When this method is requested, it responds with a view of products list that corresponds to the category passed as parameter. Follow the code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Category(string categoryName = null)
{
    if (Regex.Match(categoryName, @"\d+").Success)
    {
        int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(categoryName, @"\d+").Value);
        string sluggedCategoryName = CommodityHelpers.UppercaseFirst(CommodityHelpers.GenerateSlug(Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Name));

        if (String.Format("{0}-{1}", categoryId, sluggedCategoryName) == categoryName)
        {
            ViewBag.Title = Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Name;
            ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Products_Quantity;
            ViewBag.CurrentCategory = sluggedCategoryName;
            return View(Products.BuildListForHome(categoryId, null));
        }
        else
        {
            return View("404");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View("404");
    }
}
```

But I want to return other a specific view when "Offers" is passed as parameter.

How can I do this?

Comment: Add another optional parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (categoryName == "Offers")
    return View("SomeView", Products.BuildListForHome(categoryId, null));
```

Comment: @chiefGui: For this specific case, yes.  Depending on your application, it may make sense to have a set of categories with custom views and pass the category name as the view name.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what view to return as a parameter like so:

```
return View("Offers", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put an "if" "then" in the beginning of the method checking for Offers, and return your offers View if the conditions meet.